# Couting instructions in a Python code to predict PLC's scan time

Tags: plc

I am creating a code on Python that is made to be later implemented on a PLC.
I would like to know how long it would take for the PLC to run it.

So far the documentation of a PLC's CPU is giving me:

- Boolean  → 0.08 μs/instruction
- Move Word → 1.7 μs/instruction
- Real math → 2.3 μs/instruction

But i would need a few more details about it such as :

if A == B then: C = (D+1)*2

How would you count that ? 
To me :
- 2 Booleans (if and A == B)
- 1 Move word (Move a value to C)
- 2 Real math (one addition and one multiplication)

Is that correct ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic makes sense to me, but I do not know why you would want to do this. The processors used in PLCs have gotten so fast scan time is almost of no concern.

Comment: It is true that a PLC CPU is fast but consider that example: I need to find the area under a (discrete) curve. My curve contains 10000 points and computing the area between 2 points takes around 10 maths operations. At the end i have 20000 operations of 2.3μs which is ~50ms which can be a lot! (this is just an example I'm not trying to do that but basically, every optimization like subroutine can have a lot of computation induced)